# Структуры - сортировки, удаление, добавление объектов

Tags: массивы, c, структуры, строки

Здравствуйте. Очень бы хотел получить вашу помощь, ибо С для меня язык новый, а ВУЗе на 6 неделе 1 курса идут структуры, которые находятся в книжке в 1000 страниц С. Прата где - то (не важно) в конце. Осознать такой объём я не успеваю, поэтому многое корректно сделать не способен.

Задача: написать некую модель личного кабинета на сайте книжного магазина (прокат книг). В программу вводятся пользователем следующие данные: 1)название книги, 2)автор, 3) сколько стоит. Эти данные должны сортироваться по этим трём признакам по возрастанию убыванию (речь о цене книг) и а-я я-а по алфавиту (если речь об остальных признаках: название и автор). 
Вопросы:

1. Реализовал сортировки, но есть  проблема: строчки подобного вида `help=booksA[j].value; booksA[j].value=booksA[j+1].value; booksA[j+1].value=help;` 
   распознавать не хочет, ибо считает, что "одну сущность нельзя присвоить другой сущности" и "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением".
2. В связи с тем, что на сортировке программа стала вылетать по непонятным причинам (компилятор MS Visual Studio 2012), проверить часть программы после сортировки возможности не представилось. Не внушает у меня доверия созданные функции под удаление и добавление элементов, это лишь концепции, не проверенные на практике. Хотел бы услышать какие - нибудь идеи на их доработку или замену.

P.S. Это только C, не С+(:D) и С++. Возможно, что в С++ проблему сортировки можно было решить с помощью swap (что касается перестановки пузырьком). Сущ. функция qsort, но я бы хотел иметь в программе реализацию классического пузырька, если это возможно, тем более, что я не имею в qsort управлять возрастанием или убыванием.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

#define un 250

struct people {char name [un]; char lastname [un]; int number [un];};

struct books {char title[un]; char author[un];  int value[un]; char booksis[un]; };

void DELETEE(void) //функция удаления
  {register int f;
   struct books booksA[un];
   char l[100];
   printf("Vvedite № zapisi dlya udalenija");
   gets_s(l);
   f=atoi(l);//конвертор ASCII, возратит 0, если ничего нет
   if ((f>=0)&&(f<un)) {booksA[f].title[0]='\0';}
  }
int FREE(void) //поиск свободного места в структуре
  {register int z;
   struct books booksA[un];
   for (z=0; booksA[z].title[0]&&(z<un); ++z) {if (z==un) return -1;}
  }
void incialize(void) //помечает нулевой байт для поля - потом не используются
  {register int m;
   struct books booksA[un];
   for (m=0; m<un; ++m) {bookA[m].title[0]='\0';}
  }
int variants(void)
  {int b=0;

   printf("Chto vi hotite dalee? Enter number: ");
   printf("\n1-Posmotret' spisok zakazannih knig v poradke sakazivanija\n");
   printf("2-Otsortirovat' po ubivaniyu ceni\n");
   printf("3-Otsortirovat' po vozrastaniju ceni\n");
   printf("4-Otsortirovat' po avtoru a-ja \n");
   printf("5-Otsortirovat' po avtoru ja-a \n");
   printf("6-Otsortirovat' po nazvaniyu a-ja \n");
   printf("7-Otsortirovat' po nazvaniyu ja-a \n");
   printf("8-Udalit' element \n");
   printf("9-Dobavit' element \n");

   scanf_s("%d", &b);
  }

int main (void)
  {struct books booksA[un];
   struct people peopleA[un];
   int i,j,a,b,c,sortI, sortJ,*help;
   char *helpchar1;
   char *helpchar2;
   char *helpchar3;
   char *helpchar4;

   c=0;

   printf("Chtoby prervat' vvod i pereyti k novomy shagu nagmite ENTER posle soobjeniya o vvode novoy knigi\n");
   printf("Vvedite nazvanie knigi (<%d) # %d\n", un, c) ;

   while ((c<un)&&((scanf_s("%s", booksA[c].title)!=NULL))&&booksA[c].title[0]!='\0') //ограничитель 
     {printf("Vvedite FIO avtora knigi #%d\n",c);
      scanf_s("%s", booksA[c].author);
      printf("Vvedite cenu knigi(celoe) #%d\n",c);
      scanf_s("%f", &booksA[c].value); 
      c++;

      while (getchar()!='\n') {continue;}  //продолжаем ввод пока не нажат Enter
      if (c<un) {printf("\nVvodite nazvanie sledujushey knigi # %d\n", c);}
     }

  // b=getch();
   variants();
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=1))
     {printf("Spisok zakazannih knig: \n"); 
      for (i=0; i<c; i++)
        {printf("%s by %s: (rub) %d\n", booksA[i].title, booksA[i].author, booksA[i].value);} //1 знак после запятой

     }   
   else 
     {printf("Ne vibraly? Its bad!\n"); return 0;}
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=2)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по убыванию цены
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (booksA[j].value<booksA[j+1].value) {help=booksA[j].value; booksA[j].value=booksA[j+1].value; booksA[j+1].value=help;} 
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }

   if ((c!=0)&&(b=3)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по возрастанию цены
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (booksA[j].value>booksA[j+1].value) {help=booksA[j].value; booksA[j].value=booksA[j+1].value; booksA[j+1].value=help;}
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }

   if ((c!=0)&&(b=4)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по автору а-я
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (strcmp(booksA[j].author, booksA[j+1].author)>0) {helpchar1=booksA[j].author; booksA[j].author=booksA[j+1].value; booksA[j+1].author=helpchar1;}
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=5)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по автору я-а
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (strcmp(booksA[j].author, booksA[j+1].author)<0) {helpchar2=booksA[j].author; booksA[j].author=booksA[j+1].author; booksA[j+1].author=helpchar2;}
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=6)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по названию а-я
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (strcmp(booksA[j].title,booksA[j+1].title)>0) {helpchar3=booksA[j].title; booksA[j].title=booksA[j+1].title; booksA[j+1].title=helpchar3;}
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=7)) 
     {for (i=0; i<c; i++)   //сортировка пузырьком по названию я-а
       {for (j=0; j<c-i; j++)
          {if (strcmp(booksA[j].title,booksA[j+1].title)<0) {helpchar4=booksA[j].title; booksA[j].title=booksA[j+1].title; booksA[j+1].title=helpchar4;}
          }
       }
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s", booksA[i]);}; 
     }
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=8)) {DELETEE();}
   int g=FREE();
   int y=c+1;//счётчик для продолжения заполнения
   if ((c!=0)&&(b=9)&&(FREE()!=-1)) //добавление
     {printf("Vvedite nazvanie knigi (<%d) # %d\n", un, y) ;

     while ((y<un)&&((scanf_s("%s", booksA[y].title)!=NULL))&&booksA[y].title[0]!='\0') //ограничитель 
       {printf("Vvedite FIO avtora knigi #%d\n",y);
        scanf_s("%s", booksA[y].author);
        printf("Vvedite cenu knigi(celoe) #%d\n",y);
        scanf_s("%f", &booksA[y].value); 
        y++;

        while (getchar()!='\n') {continue;}  //продолжаем ввод пока не нажат Enter
        if (y<un) {printf("\nVvodite nazvanie sledujushey knigi # %d\n", c);}
       }
    }
    else printf("Vvod nevozmogen!");

   system("pause");
   return 0;
```

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться что за вуз и в каком городе? 

не я в хорошем смысле слова!

Comment: Для начала прочтите K&R ("Язык программирования Си" Брайан Kерниган, Деннис Ритчи там всего около 200 страниц).

--

Обратите внимание на область видимости (и соответственно время жизни переменных (это как раз Ваш случай для массивов в функциях `incialize()` и т.п.)), ввод-вывод (почему бы не использовать scanf()?), указатели и динамическое распределение памяти.

--

Потом сами поймете, как надо писать такую задачку.

(И если есть такая возможность, не учитесь программированию в винде).

Comment: @XAegis страшное дело. Это C, но какой-то странный, с MS-акцентом. 

1. Функция incialize (к счастью не используется). Что-то должна делать, но не может

2. value -- объявлен как массив int, но используется как скаляр

3. это value используется с форматом `%f` (для значений double)

Дальше не смотрел. Я не знаю, кто такой Прат, но книга Кернигана и Ритчи значительно короче...

Comment: `int FREE(void) //поиск свободного места в структуре` - о да, очень удачное имя и сигнатура.

Сортировки лучше вынести в отдельные функции (а ещё лучше использовать стандартный `qsort`). Код станет понятнее, чище.

Comment: Я не понял: это учебная задача или работа (подработка)? Если второе, то прямо-таки напрашивается применение какой-нибудь простенькой СУБД, типа Firebird. Там Ваши сортировки окажутся встроенными в язык запросов. И не нужно будет изобретать велосипед да еще на языке, которым Вы не владеете совершенно (пока что).

Comment: Учебная работа и только. Спасибо за советы. Код не окончательный, причины выше были описаны. "Хедеры <list> и <vector> -- сугубое C++, conio.h -- что-то досовское (фтопку)
Функция incialize (к счастью не используется). Что-то должна делать, но не может
value -- объявлен как массив int, но используется как скаляр
это value используется с форматом %f (для значений double)" согласен, это то теоретическое и не проверенное.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем, кто отозвался. На данном ресурсе всё всегда по - делу. Это радует.

Comment: @XAegis, а Вы вообще-то документацию читаете?

Я на M$ не пишу, но судя по доке, например, вот это

     ...scanf_s("%s", booksA[c].title)...

работать не должно (на мой взгляд их компилятор должен бы ругнуться, но проверить не могу), т.к. согласно доке

    Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

Comment: Да, это верно, но компилятор от меня сам требует такой записи. Парадокс. Так же от gets и многих других строковых функций.

Comment: у майкрософта как всегда компилятор зажигает не по юношески. Он то так позволяет писать, более того, оно нормально компилируется, но вот только работать не будет адекватно. Хотя иногда и получается со стека что-то аккуратно взять.

Comment: @avp, @KoVadim в случае C без плюсов прототип необязателен. Т.е. будет внешняя ссылка на какой-то scanf_s типа int с какими-то параметрами. Ну а до линковки там вроде ещё далеко.

Comment: Оно то скорее всего слинкуется майкрософтовым линковщиком. Но работать будет очень плохо. Сам натолкнулся на это. И пока внимательно не почитал документацию, не работало.

Comment: Есть ли достойная альтернатива Visual Studio?

Comment: Попробуйте emacs + make + gcc/g++/gdb (лучше сразу в \*nix).

Comment: @avp Ч.Петцольд восемь лет назад сказал, что альтернативы нет. И то, что VS портит мозги. http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html

Comment: пока учил основы С++ кодил в VS, и очень много косяков потом всплыло!

пришлось потом перелопачивать очень много страниц...

помог gcc\g++ и пара тестовых структур данных(вектор, список...)

java начал изучать сразу с консоли! и **ответственно заявляю что учиться программировать(компилировать) надо только через консоль!** при этом сам текст программ можно писать в чём угодно (например Sublime text)